# mysql error when connecting to tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a master table called product_data, which has several fields, with int values which i then use to join to smaller tables that i call attributes etc.

in my master table i will have a field called "colour" it has a number asigned for each record, and then i use a JOIN left to the attrib_colour table to get the actual colour name as you can see below.

```
FROM product_data
    LEFT JOIN attrib_colour ON product_data.attrib_colour = attrib_colour.id
```

My issue is, if no colour is set then the defaul value is 0 and because i have no colours set with an index value of 0 it just crashes the mysql query.

Comment: Not sure about crash but if no data is found on `attrib_colour` then also you should get data from master and non-matching data as null while doing `left join`.

Comment: im sorry that comment just went straight over my head, im not very experience with mysql this is the error i get "failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

Comment: Add the complete query into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Error on my part was a different query causing the issue which i have now fixed.

Comment: Then close the question